# Configure the statusbar to show rows

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, statusline

I want to configure the statusbar in vim to show which row I'm on. I have it currently set as

```
statusline=%l/%L\ (%3p%%)
```

I want however to do something like the following

```
statusline=%3l/%3L\ (%3p%%)
```

The problem is that I don't know how big %L is going to be before hand. Can I somehow do

```
statusline=%{length of L}l/%L\ (%3p%%)
```

so that l is always printed with the same size as L?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `:help statusline` where you can find many forms of embedding expressions, including `%!`, `%{`, and `%{%`. In this case, I might use `%{%` with an expression that calculates the length of `%L` (via `line('$')->len()`) and returns the expression `'%'.length_L.'l'`:

```
:set statusline=%{%'%'.(line('$')->len()).'l'%}/%L\ (%3p%%)
```